# Unbound module core while trying to compile ocaml file

Tags: ocaml

i'm having a problem while trying to compile an ocaml file with `ocamlc -o hello hello.ml` it gives me this error

> Error: Unbound module Core

which is weird because when i use utop and import the core std with `open Core.Std;;` it does work and import it, any ideas of how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

`open Core.Std` does not really import `core`, it just puts its values in scope so that you can refer to `Core.Std.x` as just `x`.

To import it you need to pass it to `require` the package somehow in your compiler. The easiest way is to use `ocamlfind`:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package core -linkpkg -o hello hello.ml
```

The corresponding way to do that in `utop` is by passing `-require core` on the command line or `#require "core"` in the REPL.

Comment: man, this is the ~10th SO post I've scrolled through. Thanks!